# Is HWE Kernel 5.8 supported by the Livepatch service in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kernel, canonical-livepatch

I'm thinking of installing kernel 5.8 on my 20.04 build.  Currently I'm running kernel 5.4.
Does Canonical's Livepatch service support hwe kernel 5.8 on 20.04 LTS?

Comment: In the Linked answer above the answers are incorrect.  Even when they stated that HWE kernels are not supported the Livepatch site itself says that "generic and lowlatency GA kernels are supported".  HWE is installed as a `generic` kernel, i.e. `5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1-generic`, and is supported or livepatch would fail.  So, the answers from the duplicate are incorrect.

Comment: In that case a corrected answr should posted there.

Comment: @muru Fair enough.  Wrote up an answer there.  Do you know if I can recall my Reopen vote here?  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer:  Yes

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ canonical-livepatch status
last check: 16 minutes ago
kernel: 5.8.0-41.46~20.04.1-generic
server check-in: succeeded
patch state: ✓ no livepatches needed for this kernel yet
```